# Spring 3 - Testing a controller @Autowired Servlet Context

Tags: spring-mvc, junit4

I have a controller with the following annotation

```
@Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;
```

which seems to work fine and to autowired the servlet context properly.
However when I try to run the junit I get the following exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ControllerTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: javax.servlet.ServletContext

The strange issue is that this only happened with ServletContext, I have other beans autowired on this particular controller and unit tests works fine for those.

Any advice would be very helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @bluefoot states, you should use `MockServletContext`.  For this to work, instead of auto wiring the ServletContext, you can implement [`ServletContextAware`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/ServletContextAware.html).  Spring will notice this when running in a web application context and inject the ServletContext and in the JUnit test you can call the setServletContext method to set the MockServletContext.

Comment: This is even better, Thanks krock!

Answer (score 6):

Well, your're not supposed to have a real `ServletContext` inside a junit test ambient.

You should use [MockServletContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockServletContext.html).

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I fixed it adding the following code to one of the xml files: <bean id="servletContext" class="org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext"/>